# jQuery "enlarge on hover" fails to enlarge relative to center of picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tubepress

I got some great help on getting the basic part of this down, but now I need help again :(
The javascript below is supposed to make it so that when you hover over thumbnails in a gallery, the thumbnails enlarge. I increase the height and width, but I also change the top and left offsets to compensate so that it looks like the picture is enlarging relative to the center of the thumbnail, instead of stretching out towards the bottom-right.

```
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb').hover(function() {
    var currThumb = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb[id="' + currThumb +'"]').stop().animate({height: "100", width: "118", left: "-12", top: "-15"}, "fast");
}, function() {
    jQuery('.videogall-thumb').stop().animate({height: "83", width: "98", left: "0", top: "0"}, "fast");
}
);
```

At least that's what I hoped would happen. But the thumbnails are still stretching out instead of enlarging from the center. Additionally, the thumbnail that is being enlarged ends up underneath neighboring thumbnails on the row instead of going on top of them, and it pushes the neighboring thumbnails on the row below. See what I mean here: http://oneworldyouthproject.org/tubepress-test/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `position: relative` to your `img` elements in order for the `left` and `top` positioning to work.

Comment: Thanks! That works great to solve the centering issue. But the hovered picture is still hidden under its right neighbor, and pushes its bottom neighbor away. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: You need to increase the `z-index` of those items being moused over and on mouse out you need to reset it to the default `z-index`. If that doesn't work, then you may have to set your items to `position: absolute` and manually position them relative to their parent.